# Construct filtering expression based on lexicographical ordering

Tags: python, pyarrow

I have a dataset with integer columns for `'year'`, `'month'` and `'day'`.

For a given `start_date` and `end_date` (pandas Timestamps), I want to build an expression to filter for all the rows between these dates.

I have the following working solution, which implements precedence of year over month over day manually:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pyarrow.compute as pc

def get_partition_filter(start_time: pd.Timestamp,
                         end_time: pd.Timestamp) -> pc.Expression:
    # Extract year, month, and day from start and end times
    start_year, start_month, start_day = start_time.year, start_time.month, start_time.day
    end_year, end_month, end_day = end_time.year, end_time.month, end_time.day

    # Construct filter
    return ((ds.field("year") > start_year) | ((ds.field("year") == start_year) & (ds.field("month") > start_month)) |
           ((ds.field("year") == start_year) & (ds.field("month") == start_month) & (ds.field("day") >= start_day))) & \
           ((ds.field("year") < end_year) | ((ds.field("year") == end_year) & (ds.field("month") < end_month)) |
           ((ds.field("year") == end_year) & (ds.field("month") == end_month) & (ds.field("day") <= end_day)))
```

I also have the following hack, which circumvents lexicographical ordering by treating the dates as one integer each and constructing a derived field.

```
def get_partition_filter_new(start_time: pd.Timestamp,
                             end_time: pd.Timestamp) -> pc.Expression:
    # Construct ints from dates
    start_date_int, end_date_int = (
        int(time.strftime('%Y%m%d')) for time in (start_time, end_time)
    )

    # Construct the derived field
    derived_field = (
        ds.field("year")*10**4 +
        ds.field("month")*10**2 +
        ds.field("day")
    )

    # Construct the filter expression
    return (derived_field >= start_date_int) & (derived_field <= end_date_int)
```

Is there a native way to do something like this in `pyarrow`? To rephrase the question, I am looking for something like this (pseudo-code):

```
# PSEUDO-CODE
(start_year_int, start_month_int, start_day_int) <= (ds.field("year"), ds.field("month"), ds.field("day")) <= (end_year_int, end_month_int, end_day_int)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using `pandas` this is very easy. Just create a new column that contains the timestamp and filter on that.

```py
import random

import pandas as pd

# Create some test data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "year": [random.randint(2000, 2023) for _ in range(1000)],
        "month": [random.randint(1, 12) for _ in range(1000)],
        "day": [random.randint(1, 28) for _ in range(1000)],
    }
)

# Construct a single field that holds the date
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df[["year", "month", "day"]])

# Define the filter range
start_datetime = pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01")
end_datetime = pd.to_datetime("2020-12-31")

# Filter the dataframe
df = df[(df["timestamp"] >= start_datetime) & (df["timestamp"] <= end_datetime)]
```

However, if you want to use `pyarrow` only it's a little more cumbersome. The principle is the same (create a column that contains the timestamp with the correct type), but to do this you'll have to concatenate your integer columns into a string timestamp and parse it. Then you can filter as normal. Example:

```py
import random

import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

# Create some test data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "year": [random.randint(2000, 2023) for _ in range(1000)],
        "month": [random.randint(1, 12) for _ in range(1000)],
        "day": [random.randint(1, 28) for _ in range(1000)],
    }
)

# To PyArrow table
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)


def get_partition_filter(
    t: pa.Table, start_time: pd.Timestamp, end_time: pd.Timestamp
) -> pc.Expression:
    # Convert pandas Timestamp to PyArrow Timestamps
    start_time_pa = pa.scalar(start_time, type=pa.timestamp("s"))
    end_time_pa = pa.scalar(end_time, type=pa.timestamp("s"))

    # Apply the filter
    return (ds.field("timestamp") >= start_time_pa) & (
        ds.field("timestamp") <= end_time_pa
    )


# Add a column that contains a datetime type
table = table.append_column(
    "timestamp",
    pc.strptime(
        pc.binary_join_element_wise(
            pc.cast(table["year"], pa.string()),
            pc.utf8_lpad(pc.cast(table["month"], pa.string()), 2, "0"),
            pc.utf8_lpad(pc.cast(table["day"], pa.string()), 2, "0"),
            "-",
        ),
        format=r"%Y-%m-%d",
        unit="s",
    ),
)

# Define the filter range
start_datetime = pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01")
end_datetime = pd.to_datetime("2020-12-31")

# Filter the table
table = table.filter(get_partition_filter(table, start_datetime, end_datetime))
```

Comment: Thank you. The pandas solution does not work for me, because it requires fetching all data before filtering. If I understand the second solution correctly, you are permantly adding a helper-column "timestamp" to the table? Is it possible to avoid adding a column, for example by working with "derived" fields like I did in my question?

Comment: I don't see the benefit of that.. You can always drop the column when you don't need it anymore and it won't have much of a performance impact. Also, the filter function has to return a filter statement so I don't think it's possible what you're asking.